# how to pause animation when function is called?

Tags: javascript, html, function, animation

I have a moving animation, however I want to pause the animation when the pause() function is called through user clicking a button. Not sure how to do this, any help will be appreciated.

What I have:

```
function pause() {
console.log("paused ok");
}
```

and html:

```
<img src="image1.gif" alt="img1" id="img1" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
<input id=pausebutton  class="button" type="button" value="Pause" name="pause_button"  onClick="pause()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function pause() {
  console.log("paused ok");
  var animation = document.getElementById("img1");
  animation.pause();
}
```